# Asp.net Account in windows 7?

Tags: asp.net

I want to authorize the asp.net account to access some folders in my project.

However, I get this error::

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\ProgramingPart\FromYamn\WebExercise\WebExercise\AccordionImgs' is denied.

I am using win 7 so what is the name of the asp.net account that I should use?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on a couple of things:

1. What identity is the application pool running as?
2. What IIS authentication method are you using?
3. If you are using IIS7 in Classic Pipeline Mode, what authentication method are you using for ASP.NET (see your web.config file).

Comment: thank you Matthew for rplay...

for the first question i have no idea..

for secund and third , i did not install any IIS manually ,simply i just install VS 2010 ultemate edition.

hop this help...

thanks any way...

Comment: Sounds like you are using the development webserver in which case the "application pool identity" is your own.  You need to answer 2. and 3. and your problem will be solved.

Comment: thanks matt-dot-net for replay.

for question 2 and 3 , i did not install any IIS manually ,simply i just install VS 2010 ultemate edition and i am using Microsoft server 2008 for DataBase

Comment: @samih, if that is the case, you should only need to assign permissions to the account under which you are running Visual Studio.  That *should* be enough. Take into consideration that when you eventually publish this to a hosted environment, you will likely be hosted on IIS, so you need to know how authentication works for that server also.  This is one of the reasons I recommend developing on IIS from the start, and will eventually recommend changing from Cassini and IIS 7 Express when it is released.

Comment: thanks  Matthew Abbott for replay..
in the meanwhile i don't need to use IIS. my VS and the folder running under the same account and still not working..
I need help pleas...

Comment: thank you Matthew Abbott  for help..i solve it .it was a wrong in my server side code
thank any way

Answer (score 0):

Try running visual studio as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Under Win7 the default IIS user is ApplicationPoolIdentity. This is somewhat confusing as it's not a real user account. In order to adjust the permissions you need to drop to the command line first and issue

```
icacls D:\ProgramingPart\FromYamn\WebExercise\WebExercise\AccordionImgs /grant "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool":(OI)(CI)(RX)
```

From there you can return to explorer and edit the permissions using the properties tab for the directory. Or you can simply type "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool" in the add users field in explorer, but I have a preference for icacls myself :)

Probably you want to add the permissions a bit further up the tree. In real shared hosting scenarios application pools tend to get their own, full user accounts, but Server 2008/Win7 added the app pool user so pools can be created, isolated without having to do that.

Comment: thanks blowdart for reply..

I tried your both ways but didn't work ;""IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool" is not found in my computer

Comment: Hmm ok, that's weird. Take a look at the application pool identity that your site is running it, if this is a machine that's been upgraded from Vista it will be different.

Comment: thank you blowdart for help..i solve it .it was a wrong in my server side code
thank any way

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

On the folder of your application, which might be something like:
 C:\Users\YourName\Documents\YourSite
or
 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\YourSite

Right-click the folder, choose Properties, go to the Security tab.

You need to add IIS_IUSRS to this list, and probably give full control.

Then, in IIS Manager, assuming you've set up your project folder as an application here, click on your folder/application. Then click the Authentication option. Right click the Anonymous Authentication, and check the user identity. Mine is IUSR.

Go back to your folder security, and add this user, with full control too.

Hopefully it works now!